# How to pass a struct with an matrix as pthread argument?

Tags: c, pthreads

I have the following struct:

```
typedef struct {
  int row;
  int** matrix;
} values ;
```

To fill the struct matrix I tried the following code:

```
values **v = (values **)malloc(x * sizeof(values *));
for (int z = 0; z < y; ++z)
     [z] = (values *)malloc(y * sizeof(values));
```

Where x is the number of rows and y columns.

How can I populate the arguments (`row` and `matrix`) of struct and pass as parameter to a function called by pthread?
Something similar to...

```
pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, somaLinha, v);
```

Comment: The line starting `values **v` defines a pointer to an array of pointers to your `value` struct (which could eventually be treated as a '2D array' of structures).  You then allocate an array of size `y` structures for each row of the matrix.  But none of this has done anything about the matrix embedded in each of the structures.  Are you sure that's what you wanted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you allocate the space for the struct, C is actually going to allocate the space for an integer plus the space for the pointer (which is 4+8 bytes)

You need to allocate the space for the struct, and then [allocate for the matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403150/how-do-you-dynamically-allocate-a-matrix#1403157)

```
values *v = (values *) malloc(sizeof(values));
v->matrix = (int **) malloc(y * sizeof(int *));
for (int z = 0; z < y; ++z)
    v->matrix[z] = (int *) malloc(y * sizeof(int));
```

And then you create the thread

```
pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, somaLinha, v);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Would you know how to fill the value of the row in the struct as well? And just to confirm, the function declaration looks like this: `void * somaLinha(v values)`?

Comment: As I believe this discussion does not directly refer to the question, I sent you an email with the answer.

Comment: @MathiasFalci: Note that all thread 'main' functions should have the signature `void *function(void *data);` (the name of the function and the argument is variable; the type information is not).  Your `somaLinha()` should therefore have the declaration `void *someLina(void *data)`.  Inside the function, you can use `values *vp = data;` or equivalent to get the pointer to the matrix.  The `pthread_create()` call is then OK.  You need to decide whether the thread launching code or the thread main function (`somaLinha`) releases the allocated space; it's usually best if the launch code cleans up.